# core data missing records iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a strange and serious problem.

When I am working with core data (not saving or editing or anything) just accessing the data from entity.

Sometime strangely a few records or all records are missing(deleting) from the entity when my application restarts.

I checked them by opening the SQLite database.

Can anyone have the same problem ?

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem today. It turned out I had some code for inserting test data (for debugging) that had been uncommented and it was clearing and re-filling the database with the test data every time the app started.
 It sounds to me like you're having a media issue where the storage space is actually corrupting from time to time. Did you get it fixed?